# SWT TableViewer cell does not display image unless clicked on after update

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I'm currently working with an SWT TableViewer. And I have a given it a `StyledCellLabelProvider` implementation. I have given it a set of input and it displays it fine. There is use case where a use can select rows from the table to perform certain actions on and then an icon needs to be added to a specific cell on each row that the modification was done on.

The problem I'm running into here is that the image is not showing up unless I click physically inside the tableviewer after performing the modifcation. Please note that the tableviewer's selection remains the same after the modification has been performed as well. I know the update in the `StyledCellLabelProvider` is being called after I call refresh on the tableviewer.

My question is why is it not showing up without clicking?

MyStyledCellLabelProvider

```
public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
    if (cell.getElement() instanceof Foo && ((Foo)cell.getElement()).hasBeenModified()) {
       cell.setImage(myImage);
    }
    cell.setText("ABCD");
}
```

TableViewerComposite

```
@Override
public void notifyModificationMade(Object[] modifiedObjects){
    //Update input on tableviewer
    ...
   //Refresh after updating
   tableViewer.refresh(); //Triggers the StyledCellLabelProvider to be called 
}
```

Thanks again!

EDIT:

So one piece of information I forgot is that the cell that is being updated will sometimes have a `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink` already existing inside of it instead of text and will continue to have it after the image has been added. I think this is what is causing the issue. When I removed the hyperlink code and went back to text, it worked as intended. Here is the code I'm using to add the `HyperLink` to the cell.

```
public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
    if (cell.getElement() instanceof Foo && ((Foo)cell.getElement()).hasBeenModified()) {
       cell.setImage(myImage);
       final Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),
                        SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK);
       link.setUnderlined(true);
       link.setBackground(link.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND));
       link.setForeground(link.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
       link.setText("My url");
       link.setHref(url);
       link.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter() {
                    ...
       });

       TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
       TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
       editor.grabHorizontal = true;
       editor.grabVertical = true;
       editor.setEditor(link, item, cell.getColumnIndex());
       editor.layout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.update(cell);` after your code inside `update`

From the source code of StyledCellLabelProvider.java, the `update` method says

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider#update(org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell)
     */
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        // clients must override and configure the cell and call super
        super.update(cell); // calls 'repaint' to trigger the paint listener
    }
```

The super class `OwnerDrawLabelProvider.java` forces a redraw of cell.

Comment: Just tried this and was still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Are you hitting breakpoint `cell.setImage(...)` after `update` is called ? Also your `MyStyledCellLabelProvider` implements any interface  like `ILabelProvider` ?

Comment: `MyStyledCellLabelProvider` extends `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider` and `update` is being called after the image is being set.

Comment: `update` is being called after the image is being set ? that seems to explain the behavior. During `update` it should set the image, not after `update` is already done.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. The image is being set during `update`. `super.update' is the last thing my overriden implementation of `udpate` is calling

Comment: No thing like that at all.

Comment: Ok. you are able to see the new text but not the image ?

Comment: I have updated my orginal post. The cell that the image is being added has an existing HyperLink object already in it. Do you think that this is what could be causing it?

Comment: You can try commenting that block and check if that is indeed the issue.